# Simple bouncing ball program in Java

Tags: java, bounce

I am trying to code a simple bouncing ball program. It has a rectangle and two balls in it. The balls have to bounce off the walls of the rectangle (I have coded that succesfull) and they also have to bounce off of each other. This is where I need your help. When I give the balls the same speed, they bounce fine and the program works, but I have to give the balls random speeds. When I do this the balls won't bounce anymore and just move through each other.

```
import java.applet.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class BallApplet2 extends Applet implements Runnable 
{ 
  // Begin variabelen
  int x_pos1 = 150; 
  int y_pos1 = 200; 
  int radius1 = 20; 

  int x_pos2 = 250; 
  int y_pos2 = 200; 
  int radius2 = 20;

  private float ballspeedx1 = -3;   
  private float ballspeedy1 = 0;

  private float ballspeedx2 = 3;   
  private float ballspeedy2 = 0; 


  public void init() {} 

  public void start() { 
  Thread th = new Thread (this); 
   th.start (); } 
   public void stop() {} 
  public void destroy() {} 
  public void run () {
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY); 
while (true) 
{ 
  x_pos1 += ballspeedx1;
  y_pos1 += ballspeedy1;
  x_pos2 += ballspeedx2;
  y_pos2 += ballspeedy2;  


  repaint();
  // als x_pos < 100 is draait de richting van de bal om
  if (x_pos1  < 100) {
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1; 
    x_pos1 = 100; 
  } 
  if (x_pos2  < 100) {
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2; 
    x_pos2 = 100; 
  }  
  // als x_pos > 300 is draait de richting van de bal om
  if (x_pos1  > 300) {
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1; 
    x_pos1 = 300; 
  } 
  if (x_pos2  > 300) {
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2; 
    x_pos2 = 300; 
  }                                       
  // als de x van de rode bal gelijk is aan de x en twee keer de straal van de blauwe bal, draaien beide ballen om.
  if (x_pos1 == x_pos2 + 40) {
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1;
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2;
  }
  // als de x van de blauwe bal gelijk is aan de x van de rode bal, draaien beide ballen om.
  if (x_pos2 == x_pos1 ) {
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1;
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2;
  }
  // als de x en twee keer de straal van de rode bal gelijk is aan de x van de blauwe bal, draaien beide ballen om.
  if (x_pos1 + 40 == x_pos2) {
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1;
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2;  
  }
  // als de x en twee keer de straal    
  if (x_pos2 + 40 == x_pos1) {
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1;
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2;  
  }

  try { Thread.sleep (20); } 



  catch (InterruptedException ex) {} 

Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY); }} 

public void paint (Graphics g) {

g.setColor (Color.red); 
g.fillOval (x_pos1 - radius1, y_pos1 - radius1, 2 * radius1, 2 * radius1); 

g.setColor (Color.blue); 
g.fillOval (x_pos2 - radius2, y_pos2 - radius2, 2 * radius2, 2 * radius2); 


g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawLine(80,80,80,320); // lijn links
g.drawLine(320,80,320,320); // lijn rechts
g.drawLine(80,80,320,80);  // lijn boven
g.drawLine(80,320,320,320); // lijn onder
  }




  // Einde eventmethoden


}
```

Does anyone have a solution? If so try to keep it as simple as possible please :)

Comment: This sort of thing can be tricky, do you resolve the collision at any point (physically move the balls out of collision) or just resolve the velocities

Comment: I am guessing that the speed/velocity makes the positions of the ball not match, i.e. a `x_pos2 == x_pos1` cannot occur. Maybe try to compare by `Math.abs(x_pos2-x_pos1)< bdist` (with `bdist` being calculated relatively to the speed/velocity)

Comment: Ah, yes, JScooby is right, you are comparing if their centres collide, you don't seem to use radius1 and radius 2 for your collision detection

Comment: Agreeing with @JScoobyCed, but you should probably test if the centers are too close (less than 2 times the radius) by `Math.sqrt((x_pos2-x_pos1)*(x_pos2-x_pos1)+(y_pos2-y_pos1)*(y_pos2-y_pos1)) < 2 * radius)`

Comment: Btw, to make realistic bouncing, you should probably do some more complex math. When two balls hit each other under an arbitrary angle, you cannot just invert the x and y speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 4 conditions appear to concern themselves with detecting a collision

```
  if (x_pos1 == x_pos2 + 40) {
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1;
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2;
  }
  if (x_pos2 == x_pos1 ) {
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1;
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2;
  }
  if (x_pos1 + 40 == x_pos2) {
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1;
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2;  
  }  
  if (x_pos2 + 40 == x_pos1) {
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1;
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2;  
  }
```

But they all ask if objects are at exact positions relative to other objects rather than within a range. Remember because this sort of program runs in time jumps an object may be partially within annother when the collision occurs, Changing all 4 of these conditions to just this one condition solves the problem

```
  if (Math.abs(x_pos2-x_pos1)<radius1+radius2){
    ballspeedx1 = -ballspeedx1;
    ballspeedx2 = -ballspeedx2;
  }
```

This rather than asking if the balls at specific distances from each other asks if then are overlapping at all, which provides a much safer test.

Obviously you know that these simple reverse velocity collisions are not physically correct, but an additional thing to watch out for is if a collision occurs in an overlap and (for whatever reason) the two objects aren't brought out of collision in the next time step, then annother collision occures, once this happens the two balls seem to "stick together". This can be resolved by physically moving the objects out of collision, then applying the velocity changes. This problem happens a lot with non elastic collisions but can also occure when multiple bodies collide at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for this great, simple answer, Richard! I know this program is not physically correct, but it does not have to be.

Comment: @user2919717 Glad to help. I had a feeling that was the case, I have made these series of programs myself once and went through the exact same steps

Comment: @user2919717 Btw, I would strongly recomment changing your ball position to be a double (or float), because if you go for very small time steps you will end up with position_int+=0.01; which will not change position_int

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean in your last comment. Could you explain it further?

Comment: @user2919717 At present, on each time step you add (say) 3 pixels to the position of the ball. This works fine at first, but isn't great if you want to change the frame rate, all of a sudden the speed changes when you change the frame rate. It is more usual to take the frameTime as an argument (0.02 in your case) and multiply that by a speed (measured in pixels Per Second) to get the actual movement this frame. That can be a non whole number and is better in a float/double.

Comment: Once you've done this you can add extra niceties if you're "getting serious", for example just because you ask for a 20ms sleep doesn't mean you'll get one. For a game (or physical simulation displayed in real time) sleep time is usually measured (it'll usually be what you asked for or more) and passed as an argument. That way you can deal with non uniform sleep times

Comment: Ah, I see. Will this setup I have produce any glitches? If not I will probably not change anything as this is pretty much all I needed for this program. (Had to keep it as simple as possible)

Comment: @user2919717 To be honest what you have now will be fine. It's only in case you're "moving up" from this program that I wanted to let you know