# How to switch and time animations in libGDX?

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

I have this ball object that I'm trying to play around with. I created for it a bouncing animation that when the ball hit the surface it get squash (is this the proper word in English?) and bounce back to a round form when it leave the surface.
[PROBLEM 1] Because of the different TextureRegions that create the animation, it seems as if the ball increase in size when the TextureRegions of the squash part run.
[PROBLEM 2] How should I time it so only when the ball hit the surface the three (TextureRegions) squash parts will run?

P.S
I thought of dividing the animation to two parts, when the ball hit the surface and leave it, but will it be the right solution? If so, how should I do it to make the full animation look right?

Thanks for the help. Please don't direct me to tutorials that don't cover the specifics of what I'm trying to do or to documentations in the length of a phone book that somewhere along the lines I might find the solution (well, at least be sure that it's there...).

Edit: I fixed the problem with the animation, now the timing is the only problem.
This is the code of the animation and the one I use to make it appear as if the ball bounce:

```
TextureRegion[] ballJumpAnimation = {ballJump, ballJump2, ballJump3, ballJump4, ballump5, ballJump6, ballJump7};
ballJumpAni = new Animation(0.16f, ballJumpAnimation);
ballJumpAni.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG);

// The below code is in the ball's class
public void update(float delta) {
    velocity.add(acceleration.cpy().scl(delta));
    if (position.y >= 164) {
        velocity.y = -70;
        acceleration.y = 80;
    }
    position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta));

}
```

The first three TextureRegions are when the ball touching the surface, the other four are when it is in the air. The delta is float that I get from the render method of a class the implement screen. In regards to the calculations, never was good in math and wanted to see if I can make a jumping calculation.

Comment: It depends on how you want the graphic to look, your ball is simply a circle, when it is hitting the ground it should be stretched a bit (become and ellipse and then return to its ball shape). You can achieve this even just by changing the scaling of an image without respecting its proportion for a while. The tricky part would be calculating the time for this. Basically the bottom part cannot go deeper than the ground so the upper part will get a bit closer to its center. If you can post some code that you have at the moment that would be useful

Comment: @ user3395989 which is a simple animation that simulates a ball bouncing on the ground that the motion you do this by moving the sprite, if you show me your design, and i have time, i can do one, as you can not make it to first occurred to me what you mention splitting the animation when it hits and when it rises, both two animations as in a telling but what are the key frames to be taken at each action, for example, no collides 0 to 10, and when it collides 10 to 20 is just a simple idea

Comment: Managed to deal with the animation, please read after the edit to get a better understanding of my code. Currently still struggling with the timing.

Comment: A math refresher could be this one: [What math should all game programmers know?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2029/what-math-should-all-game-programmers-know). You would be interesting in the physics part and your ball would have a positive acceleration going down, then decreasing it [in its absolute value] and the going positive for a bit of time. After that decrease it again and keep going. Have a look at [Simple bouncing ball program in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588605/simple-bouncing-ball-program-in-java) for Java implementation example.